# How to install docplex package in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, docplex

I'm trying to install docplex on a work computer and was wondering where the error is coming from when I try to install it.

I'm using Anaconda3-5.2.0 and Python 3.6.5.final.0. I'm running anaconda prompt and typing in the following code:

```
conda install -c ibmdecisionoptimization docplex
```

I get this error after I type it in:

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   https://conda.anaconda.org/ibmdecisionoptimization/win-64/repodata.json
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
>   are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>   ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /ibmdecisionoptimization/win-64/repodata.json (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
>   11001] getaddrinfo failed',))",),)

I expect the terminal to install the package, but it's giving me an error message. I tried doing a pip install and that did not help either. 
Please help, thanks!

Comment: Are you on a work connection? Possibly behind a proxy?  This is a very common issue for Windows users (e.g., [Issue 764](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/764)).

Comment: Yes  I am behind a work connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update to the latest version of Navigator.

On Navigator click on the update button on the top right of the interface or
on the terminal type

```
$ conda update conda
$ conda update anaconda-navigator
$ conda update navigator-updater
```

Comment: Okay, I can't do this because I'm using an enterprise software. Thanks anyways though.